# Running same junit suite with multiple properties

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, properties-file

I have a junit test suite, that i need to run with several different properties, so that i can have only 1 test suite, but run it several times but with different data on it.

I can make the test suite read the properties from a properties file, that i can change with an environment variable, matching that with the filename of the properties file:

```
$ export OPERATOR=myoper
```

and in my java code:

```
        String operator = System.getenv("OPERATOR");
        //Reading properties file in Java example
        Properties props = new Properties();
        //String propertiesFile = "src/test/resources/data" + operator + ".properties";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/data" + operator + ".properties");

        //loading properites from properties file
        props.load(fis);
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to iterate for all the properties files i could have, so, if i have say, 10 different properties files, that the test suite get executed that many times with all the different set of properties on the files.

I'm using maven and junit4 to run the suites, with the command:

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestSuite#testCase
```

I'll be launching the command from a Jenkins Job.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just ocurred to me that maybe the best way to deal with this is not searching for a maven or java solution, but a bash solution, maybe i can do something like "for f in $OPERATOR.properties; do export OPERATOR=f && maven command; done" i'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a little research i came up with the following command:

```
$ export OPERATOR=dataWeb*
$ for f in src/test/resources/$OPERATOR ; do export OPERATOR=$(basename "$f" | cut -d. -f1) && mvn test -Dtest=$TESTSUITE#$TESTCASE -q ; done
```

Which takes the environment variable of the operator, that is taken by the test suite to select the corresponding properties file, iterating in as many files exists in the directory with that pattern.

Hope it helps other people in the same situation. Maybe it's a better way to achieve this with the Junit + Maven + Jenkins combo that i'm not aware of.

Comment: And this is the command in the windows CMD: `set OPERATOR=Web*` and then `for %f in (.\src\test\resources\%OPERATOR%) do (set OPERATOR=%~nf& mvn test -Dtest=%TESTSUITE%#%TESTCASE% -q)`